# Exact value of a sum involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, harmonic-numbers

Could somebody tell me the exact value of this series?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(5)}}{k}
$$
where
$$
H_k^{(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{i^n}
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You may write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(5)}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{H_{k-1}^{(5)}}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^6}=\zeta(\bar{1},5)-\frac{31 \pi ^6}{30240}.
$$ 
I am not sure the [Multi Zeta Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) $\zeta(\bar{1},5)$ has a closed form in terms of known constants.

Answer (score 0):

Denote ${\bf H}^{(q)}_n(t) := \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty H_m^{(q)}/m^n \cdot t^m$. By using the formula on the bottom of the answer to [Calculating alternating Euler sums of odd powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169507/calculating-alternating-euler-sums-of-odd-powers/2251637#2251637) we have:
\begin{equation}
{\bf H}^{(5)}_1(t) = Li_6(t) + Li_1(t) Li_5(t) - Li_2(t) Li_4(t) + \frac{1}{2} [Li_3(t)]^2
\end{equation}
Since $Li_n(-1) = (1-2^{n-1})/2^{n-1} \zeta(n)$ the result is expressed through zeta functions only.